# Problem with mixture discriminant analysis in R returning NA for predictions

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a mixture discriminant analysis for a mid-sized data.frame, and bumped into a problem: all my predictions are NA.

After tracing through way too much code, I figured it had something to do with the fact that some of the coefficients in the mda turn out to be NA. I've created a smaller data.frame that still has the problem:

```
dfr<-structure(list(min_GCs_last_3_bases = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("zero", "one"), class = "factor"), cq = c(-0.334138707578632, 
-0.586150643906373, -0.474578712720667, -0.220268433139143, -0.486876877353103, 
-0.0912154554410563, 0.00341593805213764, 0.713424582672338, 
-0.448914652233824, 2.94156773625266, -0.0954835698859817, -0.238125375419562, 
-0.448914652233824, -0.0290299100261503, -0.479666688891261, 
-0.596316272919155, -0.0919665779183363, -0.394427887135795, 
-0.396749521580081, -0.338156015653477), Coverage = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("failure", "success"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("min_GCs_last_3_bases", 
"cq", "Coverage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("SMURF2_16_1", 
"MI0000437", "SMAD6_4_1", "SMAD2_8_1", "MI0003561", "SKP1_6_1", 
"MI0003556", "LTBP1_19_1", "MI0006350", "MI0006351", "TGFBR1_6_1", 
"MI0000772_1", "MI0003176", "MI0005758", "MI0003639", "MI0003641", 
"CUL1_5_1", "APC_3_1", "MI0005769", "KPNB1_5_1"))
```

When I use this data.frame like so (after loading the package mda):

```
mda(Coverage~.,data=dfr,subclasses=2)$fit$coef
```

I get this result:

```
                                [,1]        [,2]
Intercept                -0.90574883 -0.42382446
min_GCs_last_3_baseszero  1.80667985  0.85786905
min_GCs_last_3_basesone  -0.02302343  0.04884007
cq                                NA          NA
```

What troubles me about this, is:

- Why are there coefficients for both
  the values of the factor
  min_GCs_last_3_bases?
- Why are the    coefficients of cq NA?

I'm willing to assume I have completely misunderstood mda. Can someone please enlighten me? Or did I just bump into a bug?

(note: I've tried if the names of the columns had an influence: they don't)

Comment: Argl. I may have just found the cause: as most forms of DA assume (?) multivariate normality per outcome class, they don't make much sense for categorical predictors (i.e. factors), right? This may be turning into more of a stats.stackexchange question afterall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 2 failures Why were you thinking you could estimate more than two coefficients?

Comment: This is not the case in my original data.frame. I didn't consider this when posting the simplified (i.e. smaller dataset). I get the same result, however (it's even the same one that is NA, and the strange presence of both factor levels is there too).

Comment: If you have a numerically singular model matrix, most regression functions will omit variable or levels until they are able to return <something>.  Try putting the `cq` term in explicitly.